# Drawing a square with an 'x' inside

Tags: code-golf, graphical-output

Task:

- Make a program that draws the following figure line by line.
- Your program should wait for one-second after drawing each line(it can be longer, just has to be a noticeable difference) .
- Your program can **only** draw line by line (you cannot jump to another point or re-draw over a line)
- Given a positive integer n, produce an art image of the below drawing
- The angle measures should always be the same (regardless of n's value)
- However, each line's length should be 150*n pixels
- You only need to account for when n = 1, n = 2, n = 3

The picture below shows when `n` = 1

(You don't have to include the angles and side lengths in your drawing - they are just guides)

[image: dfwm]

**Answering**
- Name the language you used followed by its bytes

Example:

> **Java (swing), 500 bytes**

**Scoring**

- This is code golf. Lowest score (bytes) wins.
- [standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are **forbidden**.

Good luck!

Comment: Can you make the specifics of the dimensions etc more clear?

Comment: Would you mind showing a diagram of how long the lines should be, the angles, etc. Otherwise this may be closed as unclear.

Comment: What is the 75px labeling? And are the 150px supposed to be 150*n?

Comment: The picture shows what would be drawn if n = 1

Comment: @xnor the 75px is labeling the inner x

Comment: Despite the revisions, this looks far underspecified to me. Does the drawing have to be a single image that is modified on screen, on can it be a sequence of images that draw more and more? Do the drawn segments have to form a single Eulerian path? Does drawing a line segment mean tracing it gradually, or can it just appear at once? Does our drawing need to include the angle and length labels, or are those just guides?

Comment: Length 75px for the inner X segments seems geometrically impossible.

Comment: @xnor In my mind it was to be a single image which you would add to without tracing over another line. However, you can do a sequence if you wish. The angle and length labels are just guides. I am fixing the drawing as your last statement was correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>150</s> <s>140</s> <s>132</s> 120 bytes

*-5 bytes thanks to @Mr.Xcoder*

```python
from turtle import*
n=150*input()
for a,b in zip([0,90,30,120,30]+[135]*3+[-75,240],[n]*5+[2**.5*n,n]*2+[n]):rt(a);fd(b)
```

[Try it on Trinket](https://trinket.io/python/8f175e11f3) modified slightly to run with Python 3

Comment: Thi is exactly what I meant! I just wanted to combine a fun math problem I saw with coding. You understood the prompt and did it exactly as I imagined!

Comment: Can’t see the output.

Comment: @FrownyFrog you need to enter a number into the input field in the bottom right after pressing `run`

Comment: You updated the byte count and links, but forgot to change the code...